# Changing scrollbar position to the left, messes up my data table

Tags: css, html

When I use this in my css to change the position of the scroll bar to the left, the table data is reversed.

```
direction: rtl;
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dethdoll/sywzu1dn/) to give you an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the style for the table inside the div.scroll-it as follows

```
.scroll-it table{
     direction: ltr;
}
```